# Get custom taxonomy terms from custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

post_type: `worker`

custom `worker` taxonomy: `location`

```
get_terms_by_post_type("worker", "location");
```

Is there WordPress build-in function for that? All solutions what I found are custom functions with sql query.

Comment: Check this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

Answer (score 0):

If the `location` custom taxonomy is only registered for the `worker` post type then you can use the get_terms function to get all the terms:

```
$terms = get_terms('location', array('hide_empty' => false));
```

If the taxonomy is used on multiple post types, and you want to get just the terms used on a certain post type then you will need a custom query for that.

Comment: Then you need a custom query, there is no built-in function for that.

Comment: You can find here the same question with a custom query that does that: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14331/get-terms-by-taxonomy-and-post-type

Comment: The query itself looks fine, maybe the wordpress functions are not the same, debug it a little.

Comment: Ok, the problem was in static public declaration.